# Stumped on JS Tree... how to get the ID of currently selected <LI>?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I wish JStree had more examples of peforming AJAX actions when deleting a node, etc. Like how does it transfer the ID of selected node and pass that as a parameter? Spent a few hours and can't figure this one out.

```
<li id="10" class="open"><a style="" class="clicked" href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>fff</a> </li> 
<li id="1" class="open"><a href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>111</a> </li> 
<li id="2" class="open"><a href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>aaa</a> <ul> 
<li id="3" class="open"><a href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>Wonderful</a> <ul> 
<li id="9" class="open last"><a href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>bbb</a>
 </li> 
 </ul>
```

So if I do something like a rename, how do I get the ID in the LI tag of selected node like the node_id?

```
$("#tree2").tree({
    callback : {
    onrename : function (NODE, TREE_OBJ) {
        alert(node_id); 
    }
```

}
    });

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Your "id" values should not be purely numeric - make them start with an underscore or something so that they're valid identifiers. Otherwise, weird things might/will happen.

Comment: good point. I added nodeId in front of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin passes you the node involved; have you tried simply

```
alert($(NODE).attr('id'));
```

?

Comment: Well I'm happy for you! Good luck.  I've only played with jsTree a little bit but it looks pretty slick.

Comment: I wish they would add some examples like what you just did. It would help so much. Common usage scenarios.

Comment: I have a similar problem but what if you created a new node and by default it has no id attribute. What will be the basis of my div storage if there is no ID? I can't use the node name itself because it can have duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You should use node.id instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling for same and found a simplest way as below for key and value:

```
alert(node.id + ' ' + node.text);
```

Full Example Below:

HTML Code (have to assign `id` for each `li` either parent or child element):

```
<li id="<?php echo $result['FILTER_ID']; ?>">
```

Complete JS Code below:

```
var nodes = $('#tt').tree('getChecked');
    var s = '';
    for(var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++){
        if (s != '') s += ',';
        s += nodes[i].id + ' ' + nodes[i].text;
    }
    alert(s);
```